# Deleted Blank Row Information Remains

Tags: r, dataframe

I have this dataframe:

```
Id         weight sex 
Blank row
1            150   F
2            120   M
3            140   M
4            100   F
5            90    F
```

So, I used this command to delete the blank row:

```
new.dt <- dt[is.na(dt$Id) | dt$Id != "",]
```

But, when I will do the statistical the blank row still considered, for example:

```
str(new.dt$sex)


 Factor w/ 3 levels "","F","M"
```

How I delete this blank information from my analysis?

Comment: We need `droplevels`  i.e. `new.dt <- droplevels(new.dt)`

Comment: I did it. Sorry, but what should happen?

Comment: the unused levels are removed

Comment: Now, it's work. Thanks. Please, insert your answer. =0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `droplevels` to drop any unused factor levels in any of the columns

```
new.dt <- droplevels(new.dt)
```